# JSX string interpolation into a component name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have this code...

```
import React from 'react';
import Fade from 'react-reveal/Fade';
import { Novice } from '../../../Icons/Novice';
import { Apprentice } from '../../../Icons/Apprentice';
import { Explorer } from '../../../Icons/Explorer';
import { Advocate } from '../../../Icons/Advocate';
import { Profesional } from '../../../Icons/Profesional';
import { Ambassador } from '../../../Icons/Ambassador';

export const ProfileType = (props) => {
  const {
    label = 'Apprentice',
  } = props;
  return (
    <Fade top delay={2100}>
      <div className="profile-card__work-type">
        {
        /* {label === 'Novice' && <Novice />}
        {label === 'Apprentice' && <Apprentice />}
        {label === 'Explorer' && <Explorer />}
        {label === 'Advocate' && <Advocate />}
        {label === 'Profesional' && <Profesional />}
        {label === 'Ambassador' && <Ambassador />} */
        }
        { `< ${label} />` }
        <span className="profile-card__work-type-text">
          {' '}
          {label}
        </span>
      </div>
    </Fade>
  );
};
```

I want to use the 'label' variable as the name of my component and I'm trying to use string interpolation to use it like this `` { `< ${label} />` } `` but it just prints out the string < Novice/> to screen.

[image]

How can use the label varible as the name of the component instead of the several lines of conditionals?

Best wishes,
Nicolas

Answer (score 2):

Use an object to store your components...

```
const obj = {
  Novice: <Novice />,
  Apprentice: <Apprentice />,
  Explorer: <Explorer />,
  Advocate: <Advocate />,
  Profesional: <Profesional />,
  Ambassador: <Ambassador />
};
```

And then access the object using the label.

```
{obj[label]}
```

Comment: Super cool! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put `< ${label} />` and expect it to be evaluated as a Component if your really want to do this you have to use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop on a `<div/>` or something and give it a valid html String. But as the name of the prop suggests its dangerous given the possibility of remote code execution attacks.

Another way of going about this and probably the best way, like the other Answer suggests is putting your Components already in an Array or as properties of an Object and accessing them through the index of the Component in the Array or the key of the Object property.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will use the elegant solution of putting the components in an object and referencing the key. Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: Cool! now you can accept Andy's answer so that others can benefit from this solution if they try to do the same thing.